# Elasticsearch: sort clause does not seem to work for some specific character combinations for kuromoji_tokenizer analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, kuromoji

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "attribute.sortable": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Results:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "example_1",
    "_type": "example_1",
    "_id": "A2Ff26qFaV",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "attributes": {
        "attribute": "サヨ",
      }
    },
    "sort": [
      "サヨ"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_index": "example_2",
    "_type": "example_2",
    "_id": "A2Ff26qFaV",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "attributes": {
        "attribute": "シヨ",
      }
    },
    "sort": [
      "シ"
    ]
  }
]
```

The sort is working on the characters in attribute field for `example_1` doc but not for `example_2` doc.

Observed this in 3 instances in total for these strings:

- `シヨ`
- `ヲシ`
- `シヲ`

Tried different combinations of the characters but issue seems but be with the mentioned specific characters in that order.